# Is there a way to have an image expand the entire page on my Django based website?

Tags: html, css, django

[image]

I have a django based website and am having trouble with images filling up the entire screen or fitting to the screen size. Attatched is a photo of my issue. I've checked all my margin and border settings and everything is set to 0, yet the picture doesn't fill up the entirety of the screen. Anyone know a solution to this? Much appreciated. I'm trying to get the left and right borders on the side of the image to not exist, and to be covered by the image instead.

````
  <img class="image1" src="xxx" style="width:100%; margin-top:-25px;"/>
  <div class="image2" style="height: 725px;"><form action="/order"><input type="submit" value="Order Online"/ style="position:absolute; bottom:0; margin-bottom: 265px; margin-left: 383px; background-color: #262626; color:white; width:275px; height:70px; font-size:26px; font-family: Lucida Console">
  </div>```
````

Comment: what is the width of the parent div of the image ?

Comment: @Wahalez It wasn't specified but i just made it 100% and the issue remains

Comment: The image takes 100% of the width of it's parent tag. This means that something in the parent tag is wrong, can be anything like padding , width, etc. You will need to provide more code so people will be able to locate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
* {  margin: 0;  padding: 0; }
```

As seen in the picture, your header is also not full width.

Also, press F12 to open Developer Tools and click on element inspector and hover around your image, it will show you the margins in colored form, just click there and see in the CSS pane you will find the class which is implementing the margins.